# Creating a new theme

Tags: layout, php, theme

I am new to magento. Trying to create my own theme. I have gone through the designers guide.

I created a folder `example` inside `base` folder as shown below:

```
app --> design --> frontend --> base --> default --> example
```

In the "example" folder, I added the following directory structure:

```
example --> layout --> page.xml
        --> template  --> page --> html --> footer.phtml
```

**page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<default>
    <block type="page/html" name="root">
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"/>
    </block>
</default>
```

**footer.phtml**

```
<div>hello</div>
```

I added the above theme to my frontend page through admin panel something like this:

```
admin panel --> system --> design --> Add design change --> store         =  "english"
                                                            custom design =  "example"
```

When I refreshed my frontend page, it is blank instead of showing "hello" text. Can someone highlight what step I am missing to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1>

```
app\design\frontend\default\create_your_theme_folder (example)

than copy all folder and files from the bellow location

`app\design\frontend\base\default\`

from this location and put in your new above created (example) folder
```

Step 2>

```
skin\frontend\default\create_your_theme_folder (example)

than copy all folder and files from the bellow location

`skin\frontend\base\default`

from this location and put in your new above created (example) folder, all css,js and skin images should be in this folder
```

Step 3>

```
system --> design --> Add design change > Custom Design > select your_new_created_theme (example).
```

[Also click here for batter understanding of Package & Theme](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/create-a-custom-theme-in-magento/)

Done

Comment: Correction: Do not copy all files, just copy the ones where you need changes in the output. Same for the skin folder, only copy custom.css and include this) or only copy styles.css. Magento will automatically take the files that are missing from the base folder. You will lose the ability to update Magento if you override all files because you will need to update all custom files manually in that case.

Comment: I just want to show a text "hello" in my page. I don't want to copy any stuff which is already there.

Comment: @Mr_Green These are the steps to create new theme as you asked **Trying to create my own theme**

Comment: @DasarathiSwain thanks for helping man but I really don't like the idea of copying the existing files. I am going through the link which you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

check this post for more info.
[How to create new theme OR copy base theme to another theme in magento](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-create-new-theme-or-copy-base.html)

Comment: Please provide more details about what is found in the page you suggested. Single link answers are not the best.

Comment: Thank you Marius but there is a more details in that page about what i found there.